# MAUI android, how to reference a .JAR library

Tags: c#, android, dll, jar, maui

We are creating application for android device that works as handy terminal (with barcode reader, RFID reader, LED, 10-key keyboard).
The device's maker provide a SDK in the JAR format, to be used with Android Studio for example.
I have read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code), but this not applies to JAR files.
How I can reference an JAR library in MAUI project?
Thank for your time,
Antonio

Comment: I haven't tried but see this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1340#discussioncomment-3428075

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Koji,
I had already checked some issues (1340,1475,8634).

The correct template is .NET MAUI class library (*must be*); but the 'Build Action' must be configured inside the project file ".csproj".
Although the "Build Action=none" in properties window, inside the project file I added the following lines

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">
    <EmbeddedJar Include="classes.jar" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After build the project, a sketch class ("PlatformClass1") is created automatically for each platform.
After that, it is now possible to create objects with the contents of the 'jar' library.
[image]